# Change yTrue in custom metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to implement GAN in Keras, and I want to use `One-sided label smoothing` trick, i.e. put the label of True image to be `0.9` instead of `1`. However, now the built-in metrics `binary_crossentropy` does not do the correct thing, it's always 0 for True image.

Then I tried to implement my own metrics in Keras. I want to convert all `0.9` label to be `1`, but I'm new to Keras and I don't know how to do that. Here's what I intend:

```py
# Just a pseudo code
def custom_metrics(y_true, y_pred):
    if K.equal(y_true, [[0.9]]):
        y_true = y_true+0.1
    return metrics.binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)
```

How should I compare and change the `y_true` label? Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:
The output of the following code is:

```py
def custom_metrics(y_true, y_pred):
    print(K.shape(y_true))
    print(K.shape(y_pred))
    y_true = K.switch(K.equal(y_true, 0.9), K.ones_like(y_true), K.zeros_like(y_true))
    return metrics.binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)
```

`Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
Tensor("Shape_1:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)`

ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [?,?], [?,?].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where):

```
y_true = tf.where(K.equal(y_true, 0.9), tf.ones_like(y_true), tf.zeros_like(y_true))
```

Alternatively, You can use [keras.backend.switch](https://keras.io/backend/#switch) function for that.

```
keras.backend.switch(condition, then_expression, else_expression)
```

Your custom metrics function would look something like below:

```
def custom_metrics(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.switch(K.equal(y_true, 0.9),K.ones_like(y_true), K.zeros_like(y_true))
    return metrics.binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)
```

Test code:

```
def test_function(y_true):
    print(K.eval(y_true))
    y_true = K.switch(K.equal(y_true, 0.9),K.ones_like(y_true), K.zeros_like(y_true))
    print(K.eval(y_true))

y_true = K.variable(np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9]))
test_function(y_true)
```

output:

```
[0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I still got wrong by running your code exactly the same, where my y_true is initialized by `y_true = np.ones((50, 1))*0.9`, and I got error msg: `ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [?,?], [?,?].`. I know I should change the code, but I don't know where. Can you take a look of this question again? I'm new to Keras, and thank you so much if you can help me! @Anubhav Singh

Comment: @PiggyWenzhou, show me your code. I ran it and it's working.

Comment: Thanks for your response! @Anubhav Singh I edited the post and showed my code and the shape of y_true, y_pred above.

Comment: @PiggyWenzhou, try this line instead: `y_true = tf.where(K.equal(y_true, 0.9), tf.ones_like(y_true), tf.zeros_like(y_true))` Don't forget to import tensorflow as tf

Comment: Thanks @AnubhavSingh, it works! May I ask why the previous code was wrong?

Comment: Nope. It wasn't wrong. It has more to do with keras backend, I think. I updated this code above. Please accept it incase your problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2014. In fact, both codes are working on my laptop.